# A bash script to square a tall image of a long text column?

Tags: bash, shell-script, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Ever seen a print of a long discussion thread? Looks like the picture of a skyscraper… with only the building in it! So what I generally do — **manually!** — is break up the image into segments, and then use this script to stack them side by side using imagemagick:

```
for f in "$@"
do 
   h=($(sips -g pixelHeight "$f" | grep -o '[0-9]*$'))
   if [[ $h -gt $height ]]; then 
      height=$h
   fi
done
convert +append "$@" -geometry x$height ~/Desktop/Hcombined.png
```

How can I extend it to do the whole thing on its own?

Comment: What doesn't this do that you want it to do? (What does it do already?)

Comment: Does it really need to be a _bash_ script or might some other solution be acceptable?

Comment: As I mentioned, @roaima, the aforementioned script *stacks the segments side by side*. What it doesn't do is break the tall image into the right number of segments to turn it into a square image. It doesn't necessarily need to be a bash script, but if it is I can set it as a service, as I've done with the stacking script above.

Comment: You didn't actually tell us what the script did - or didn't - do. What you did was to explain the entire process (which is good) without clearly identifying the part your existing script played. I trust my edit clarifies that correctly.

Comment: My printouts of discussion threads are not anything like yours.  (-:  This is not a universal.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about obtaining a target aspect ratio is to use a loop starting with the default rectangular output, testing the aspect ratio, adjusting the column height, splitting, and combining again then back to test aspect ratio...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dunnit (I think):

```
for f in "$@"
do
    size=($(sips -g pixelWidth -g pixelHeight "$f" | grep -o '[0-9]*$'))
    n=$(echo "scale=3;sqrt(${size[1]}/${size[0]})" | bc)
    convert -crop 1x$n@ +repage "$f" "${f%.*}_%d.${f##*.}"
    convert +append "${f%.*}_*.${f##*.}" "${f%.*}_sq.${f##*.}"
    rm "${f%.*}_"*
done
```